# torch FloatTensor toString method?

Tags: lua, torch

I have a torch.FloatTensor that is 2 rows and 200 columns. I want to print the lines to a text file. Is there a toString() method for the torch.FloatTensor? If not, how do you print the line to the file? Thanks.

I can convert the FloatTensor into a Lua table:

```
    local line = a[1]

    local table = {}
    for i=1,line:size(1) do
        table[i] = line[i]
    end
```

Is there an easy way to convert the Lua table to a string, so I can write it to file? Thanks!

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any reference to a `toString` method of any kind on what I think is the correct documentation page: https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the Q.

Comment: There are some great answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168058/lua-beginner-table-dump-to-console) which can help you now

Answer (score 2):

There is a built-in table conversion called [`torch.totable`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/dddfc3c/doc/utility.md#table-torchtotableobject). If what you want to do is save and load your tensor, then it's even easier to use Torch native [serialization](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/dddfc3c/doc/serialization.md) like `torch.save('file.txt', tensor, 'ascii')`.