# How to point 2d array directly with one parameter?

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
    arr = {
       {'a',1},
       {'b',2},
       {'c',3}
}

    print(arr[1][1])
    print(arr[2][2])
    print(arr[2])
```

output would be

**a** **2** **table: 0x1e41080**, This may be a very newbie question for you guys. But even though it is really embarrassing to ask such question here, I ask because couldn't find solution in online. Is there a way that can point whole table of table? Like I want to point {'b',2} instead of the address of array/table.

Comment: Do you mean "print" instead of "point"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168058/lua-beginner-table-dump-to-console/42062321#42062321

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you call by "point 2d array", as there's no pointers in Lua.

There's also no 2d arrays in Lua, there's tables of tables.

What you get with `arr[2]` is exactly one value of inner table that you can pass around. It's not "just address", it's a table that you can read/write anywhere later. You see something that look as an address because that's default behavior for `print` for tables.

```
local arr = {
       {'a',1},
       {'b',2},
       {'c',3}
}

local function display(v)
    print(v[1], v[2])
end

display(arr[1])
display(arr[2])
display(arr[3])
```

Note that you can't have pointer (a reference) to some element within the table. You need two values to address individual elements of a table - a table itself and the value of its index (which is not necessarily a number or a text).

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to do it. If your tables all have the same structure, you can use this to get a string:

```
('{%q,%d}'):format(element[1], element[2])
```

If your tables are more complex, you can use a loop with more complex code.