# How to implement combinations tail-recursively?

Tags: lua, tail-recursion

I'm teaching myself Lua by reading Ierusalimschy's *Programming in Lua* (4th edition), and doing the exercises.  Exercise 6.5 is

> Write a function that takes an array and prints all combinations of the elements in the array.

After this succinct statement the book gives a hint that makes it clear that what one is expected to do is to write a function that prints all the *C*(*n*, *m*) combinations of *m* elements from an array of *n* elements.

I implemented the `combinations` function shown below:

```
function combinations (array, m)

  local append = function (array, item)
    local copy = {table.unpack(array)}
    copy[#copy + 1] = item
    return copy
  end

  local _combinations
  _combinations = function (array, m, prefix)
    local n = #array
    if n < m then
      return
    elseif m == 0 then
      print(table.unpack(prefix))
      return
    else
      local deleted = {table.unpack(array, 2, #array)}
      _combinations(deleted, m - 1, append(prefix, array[1]))
      _combinations(deleted, m, prefix)
    end
  end

  _combinations(array, m, {})

end
```

It works OK, but it is not tail-recursive.

Can someone show me a tail-recursive function that does the same thing as `combinations` above does?

(For what it's worth, I am using Lua 5.3.)

**NB:** I realize that the exercise does not require that the function be tail-recursive.  This is a requirement I have added myself, out of curiosity.

**EDIT:** I simplified the function slightly, but removing a couple of nested functions that were not adding much.

Answer (score 1):

There is a third option, one that doesn't have a snake eating it's tail. Although recursion with tail-calls don't lead to stack overflow, I avoid doing so out of personal preference. I use a while loop and a stack that holds the information for each iteration. Within the loop you pop the next task from the stack, do the work, then push next task onto the stack. I feel it looks cleaner and it's easier to visualize the nesting.

Here is how I would translate your code into the way I would write it:

```
function combinations(sequence, item)
    local function append(array, item)
        local copy = {table.unpack(array)}
        copy[#copy + 1] = item
        return copy
    end

    local stack = {}
    local node = { sequence, item, {} }

    while true do
        local seq = node[ 1 ]
        local itm = node[ 2 ]
        local pre = node[ 3 ]

        local n = #seq
        if itm == 0 then
            print(table.unpack(pre))
        elseif n < itm then
            -- do nothing
        else
            local reserve = {table.unpack(seq, 2, #seq)}
            table.insert(stack, { reserve, itm, pre })
            table.insert(stack, { reserve, itm-1, append(pre, seq[ 1 ]) })
        end

        if #stack > 0 then
            node = stack[ #stack ] -- LIFO
            stack[ #stack ] = nil
        else
            break
        end
    end
end
```

You can use this while-loop stack/node technique for just about any recursive method. Here is an example where it's applied to printing deeply nested tables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42062321/5113346

My version, using your input example gives the same output: 
`1   2   3
1   2   4
1   2   5
1   3   4
1   3   5
1   4   5
2   3   4
2   3   5
2   4   5
3   4   5`.

Forgive me if it doesn't work with other passed params because I didn't try to solve the answer to the exercise but rather just rewrite the code in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found one way to do this:

```
function combinations (array, m)

  local dropfirst = function (array)
    return {table.unpack(array, 2, #array)}
  end

  local append = function (array, item)
    local copy = {table.unpack(array)}
    copy[#copy + 1] = item
    return copy
  end

  local _combinations
  _combinations = function (sequence, m, prefix, queue)
    local n = #sequence
    local newqueue
    if n >= m then
      if m == 0 then
        print(table.unpack(prefix))
      else
        local deleted = dropfirst(sequence)
        if n > m then
          newqueue = append(queue, {deleted, m, prefix})
        else
          newqueue = queue
        end
        return _combinations(deleted, m - 1,
                             append(prefix, sequence[1]),
                             newqueue)
      end
    end
    if #queue > 0 then
       newqueue = dropfirst(queue)
       local newargs = append(queue[1], newqueue)
       return _combinations(table.unpack(newargs))
    end

  end

  _combinations(sequence, m, {}, {})

end
```

This version is, I think, tail-recursive.  Unfortunately, it does not print out the results in as nice an order as did my original non-tail-recursive version (not to mention the added complexity of the code), but one can't have everything!

---

**EDIT:** Well, no, one *can* have everything!  The version below is tail-recursive, *and* prints its results in the same order as does the original non-tail-recursive version:

```
function combinations (sequence, m, prefix, stack)
  prefix, stack = prefix or {}, stack or {}

  local n = #sequence
  if n < m then return end

  local newargs, newstack
  if m == 0 then
    print(table.unpack(prefix))
    if #stack == 0 then return end
    newstack = droplast(stack)
    newargs = append(stack[#stack], newstack)
  else
    local deleted = dropfirst(sequence)
    if n > m then
       newstack = append(stack, {deleted, m, prefix})
    else
       newstack = stack
    end
    local newprefix = append(prefix, sequence[1])
    newargs = {deleted, m - 1, newprefix, newstack}
  end

  return combinations(table.unpack(newargs)) -- tail call

end
```

It uses the following auxiliary functions:

```
function append (sequence, item)
  local copy = {table.unpack(sequence)}
  copy[#copy + 1] = item
  return copy
end

function dropfirst (sequence)
  return {table.unpack(sequence, 2, #sequence)}
end

function droplast (sequence)
  return {table.unpack(sequence, 1, #sequence - 1)}
end
```

Example:

```
> combinations({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 3)
1   2   3
1   2   4
1   2   5
1   3   4
1   3   5
1   4   5
2   3   4
2   3   5
2   4   5
3   4   5
```

Ironically, this version achieves tail-recursion by implementing its own stack, so I am not sure it is ultimately any better than the non-tail-recursive version...  Then again, I guess the function's `stack` actually lives in the heap (right?), because Lua's tables are passed around by reference (right?), so maybe this is an improvement, after all.  (Please correct me if I'm wrong!)