# Write LuaTable to file

Tags: lua, luaj

I'm trying to write a table with LUAJ and I want to export it to a file. Is it possible?

```
final LuaTable innerTable = new LuaTable();
innerTable.set("key", "value");

final LuaTable parentTable = new LuaTable();
parentTable.set("parentKey", innerTable);
```

The output file should contain something like this:

```
table = {
    ["parentKey"] = {
         key = "value"
    }
}
```

I don't find any option to export the content of my parentTable to a file.

Thanks.

Comment: I had added quotes to the "key" word by mistake. Anyway my question is about how to print the output of that table. If the output is not the expected then I will fix it once I get the result :). Thanks.

Comment: There should be no Java tag. It shouldn't matter what language LUA is written in.

Comment: You are right, changed.

Comment: So your question is: how to generate object lua code based on object created in luaj?

Comment: You should check answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168058/how-to-dump-a-table-to-console)

Comment: Thanks Leszek, thats what I was looking for, although I thought there would be something more straight forward. I think I will dump it directly with Java and forget about Luaj.